# Conditionally opening page on form submit with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to set a conditional page load on a Form Submit, following "If user selects [x] option, send them to [x] page" logic.  I'm really not that familiar with JavaScript, but this seemed to be the easiest way to go about it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form id="page1" action="javascript:OpenWindow()" method="post">
    <fieldset id="mainSelection">
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="A" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="B" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="C" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="D" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton">Next</button>
</form>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function OpenWindow() {
        var choice = document.getElementByClassName("radio-button").value
            if (choice == A) {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
            else if (choice == B) {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
            else if (choice == C) {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
            else {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
        }
</script>
```

What am I not doing correctly here?

Comment: Using string literals without quotation marks.

Comment: @raina77ow where am I doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with a few changes.

- Add onsubmit="OpenWindow()" to the form element
- Changing how you get the selected element
- quotes around your conditional ('A', 'B', etc)

Here's a link to a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qajxh

So it looks like this:

```
<form onsubmit="OpenWindow()" id="page1" action="javascript:OpenWindow()" method="post">
    <fieldset id="mainSelection">
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="A" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="B" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="C" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
            <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="D" name="sel1"> text</label><br />
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton">Next</button>
</form>
```

With js like this:

```
function OpenWindow() {
    var choice = document.getElementById("page1");
    choice = choice.sel1.value;

    if (choice == 'A') {
        window.open('http://www.website.net');
    }
    else if (choice == 'B') {
        window.open('http://www.website.net');
    }
    else if (choice == 'C') {
        window.open('http://www.website.net');
    }
    else {
        window.open('http://www.website.net');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your form works normally without the javascript, why not try changing the forms action with Javascript, instead of telling the form to go out of its norm and use javascript to open the window.

```
<form id="page1" action="http://www.website.net" method="post">
<fieldset id="mainSelection">
    <input type='radio' value='http://www.website.net' name='sel1' onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("page1").action = this.value;' />
    ...
</fieldset>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Which ever radio button you have set as default, you can set the default action to the form to that buttons URL.

**EDIT (Alternative method that uses the same HTML you have)**

To take what you have, alter your javascript to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function OpenWindow() {
    // grab the elements by name (array)
    var choice = document.getElementsByName("radio-button");
    // loop through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < choice.length; i++ ) {
        // grab only the checked one
        if (choice[i].checked) {
            if (choice[i].value == A) {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
            else if (choice[i].value == B) {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
            else if (choice[i].value == C) {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            } else {
                window.open('http://www.website.net');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to add a comment to anothers post, but you don't give every element a different class name, else you defeat the purpose of the radio buttons only allowing you to select one at a time.

Comment: okay...hmm.  So in your implementation, in the `getElementById`, would I use the ID of the form for each option?

Edit: trying your alternate code out now.

Comment: the form will automatically go to the page you have set in the 'action' so you can use javascript to alter the action to go to the website you want. You just change that whenever an option is clicked.

Comment: With the way you have it now, it makes no sense to use a form tag, why not simply have the input's onclick do a window.open? My first suggestion was to utilize the forms intent (assuming you have other variables you have to pass along with the options).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this does what you think it does. I can't test this either but I'm pretty sure that calling `getElementByClassName("radio-button")` will return all 4 labels, since they all have the class `radio-button`

Comment: yeah, but doesn't the `.value` tacked on the end make it pull what the assigned value is instead?

Comment: okay...so do I need to give every element a different class name then?  Would I need to repeat the `getElementByClassName("name")` for each one?

Comment: what you can do is give every radio button an id and then use `getElemenmtById(id).checked` to tell if its been checked.